# Best way to use .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I've multiple arrays which I need to loop through.

Below is the code I've written,How can I avoid multiple forEach.

```
  @Input() content: any;
  public sections:any;
      ngOnInit() {        
        this.content.forEach(content => {
          content.block.forEach(response => {
            this.service.createComponent(response, type);
          });
        });
      }
```

How can I reduce the above lines, and improve my code quality ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. But, `this.content.map(data => this.sections = data.sections)` sets `this.sections` to the last `data.sections` of `content`

Comment: not sure how you expect to not do two loops....

Comment: yes. and `this. sections` is as `array`

Comment: SO is not a primary place for _code review's_, [codereview.se] might be. Also, asking for _code improvement_ is both too broad and opinion-based, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `array.map` is NOT for looping. That's `array.forEach`'s job. `array.map` is used to create an array from another array, optionally transforming each value.

---

```
this.content.map(data => this.sections = data.sections);
```

What this does is assign the last item in `this.content` to `this.sections`. You do not need `array.map` to do this. You can simply grab the last item via its index.

```
this.sections = this.content[this.content.length - 1]
```

---

You cannot avoid multiple loops if your data is nested. But what you could do to improve readability is to turn the nested loop into a flat series of loops. In your code, what you're after is the `response`. So let's flatten `this.sections` first, *then* loop through it.

```
this.sections
  .map(rjfBlock => rjfBlock.rjf)
  .reduce((c, rjf) => [...c, ...rjf], [])
  .forEach(response => {
    const type = this.contentMappings[response.type]
    this.service.createComponent(response, type)
  })
```

Let's break this down:

- `.map` collects all `rjf` arrays into an array. At this point, we have an array of arrays.
- `.reduce` flattens the array by merging each array into one array. At this point, we have a one-level array of responses.
- `.forEach` - loops through each response.

Comment: getting this error `this.sections.map is not a function`, but when inspected `this.sections` this shows the list of arrays